# Android CheckBox onCheckedChangeListener fires twice

Tags: android, checkbox

I have setup a checkbox, whose checked status is set when the user changes the date on a DatePicker dialog.  I have set up the onCheckedChangeListener to display a toast when the user has changed the date.  In my testing, whenever I change the date on the DatePicker Dialog, the toast fires twice.  I only need this to fire once.

I would appreciate any advice on this.  Thanks.

```
//Here is the code -
//In the DatePicker - 
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {   

    String s = Integer.toString(year) + "/" +
    Integer.toString(monthOfYear) + "/" +
    Integer.toString(dayOfMonth);

        FreshMoonMainActivity.tvGregDate.setText((CharSequence)s);
        FreshMoonMainActivity.chkOne.setChecked(true);
        //FreshMoonMainActivity.Do
    }
//In FreshMoonMainActivity -
public void SetUpCheckOne(){
    chkOne = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkOne);
    chkOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean isChecked

    //if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
    if(isChecked){
           chkOne.setChecked(false);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Checkbox stuffer",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: post the code... for it

Comment: In the DatePickerDialogFragment -

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin - I have just added the code.  Please take a look.

Comment: you said "whenever I change the date on the DatePicker Dialog" but its a checkboxlistener

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin - Please take a look at the DatePicker code.  When the date is changed, I set a text box to show the selected date, and I also set the Checked status of the checkBox to true.  This is what I am trapping with the check box listener.  There are a couple of other controls also, where a user can make a selection.  Whenever the user changes any value in any of these controls, I want to run a particular set of functions to run.  My idea is to get each control to set the check box, and then use the checkbox listener to start off my functions.